# How to paint a QLinearGradient?

Tags: c++, qt, gradient, qpainter

In "C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4" gradients are briefly mentioned, and there is a sample code that creates a QLinearGradient object, but they don't say how to actually draw it on a QPainter.

```
QLinearGradient gradient(50, 100, 300, 350);
gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt::white);
gradient.setColorAt(0.2, Qt::green);
gradient.setColorAt(1.0, Qt::black);
```

So after I've created the QLinearGradient with this code, how do I actually draw it on the QPainter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use it to construct a [`QBrush`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbrush.html#QBrush-10) to use in a `QPainter` in your widget's paint event.